# GetProcAdress returns always zero

Tags: api, loadlibrary, kernel32

I encountered a really mysterious problem. Using the function GetProcAddress, I always get zero.

```
Debug.Print(GetProcAddress(LoadLibraryExA("kernel32"), "CreateProcess"))
```

This line returns always zero no matter if I use "CreateProcess", "LoadLibrary" or something else. Why is this so?

Declaration of the functions:

```
Declare Function LoadLibraryExA Lib "kernel32" (ByVal name As String) As IntPtr
    Declare Ansi Function GetProcAddress Lib "kernel32" (ByVal handle As IntPtr, ByVal name As String) As IntPtr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the "CreateProcess" API is actually either `CreateProcessW` or `CreateProcessA` depending on if you're using the UNICODE API or not.

Comment: Even if I use them, it still returns zero :\

Comment: What is `LoadLibraryExA()` returning?  Maybe its declaration needs to be marked as `Ansi` as well (I haven't had a chance to lookup what VB will do by default).

Comment: Actually, you don't have enough parameters in your declaration of `LoadLibraryExA()`. Try changing it to `LoadLibraryA()` which takes only a name.